# Lissajous curve - highest velocity

Tags: trigonometry

We have the following parametric representation:

$$x(t) = 2\cos t - \cos(2t)$$

$$y(t) = 2\sin t - \sin (2t) $$

A point P is described by the above equations. Voor $t=0$ and $t=2\pi$ P is in (1,0). We want the highest velocity of point P.

So we can find the velocity with $$ v(t) = \sqrt{ (x'(t))^2 + (y'(t))^2} $$

In the correction sheet, they find the derivatives and put them in the root, and eventually, after some algebra, end up with $$ v = \sqrt{8 - 8 \cos t}$$

Instead of taking its derivative and setting it equal to 0, they fill in $t=-1$ and get $v=4$. In my book it also says that you can use mathematical reasoning (so without calculations) to fill in -1 or 1 for $\sin t$ or $\cos t$.

But why can we assume the maximum speed is always attained at $t = \arcsin (1 / -1 )$ or $t = \arccos (1 / -1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since $v'=\dfrac{asin(t)}{...}=0$ means that $sin(t)=0$ which means $cos(t)=1 \ or -1$

Comment: How did you obtain that first expression? And does this always hold?

Comment: notice that if $f=\sqrt{r(t)}$ then $$f'=\dfrac{r'(t)}{2\sqrt{r(t)}}$$

Comment: if you ganna solve $f'=0$ it is enough to solve $r'=0$.

Comment: Isn't the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ equal to $\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: @Phaptitude: it is true, if there is function $r(x)$ instead of $x$, it is the result by chain rule.

Comment: @Phaptitude: check this http://www.ditutor.com/derivatives/derivative_square.html

Comment: Aha, I understand, thanks.